# RoR 3.1 - button_to_function to lock user

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to figure out the best way to lock a user account from my user/views/index page. I am attempting to use the button_to_function method, but can't figure out the proper way to do it.

I have a simple method in my User model to accomplish this:

```
*def self.lock_user(id)
  user = User.find(id)
  user.update_attribute(:locked_at, Time.now)
end*
```

Can I call this method directly in my _user.haml.html file.

I'm attempting the following, but it simply toggles every 'user':

```
*@user.each do |user|
.
.
  - if user.locked_at.nil?
    %td= button_to_function "lock", User.lock_user(user.id), :class => "lock_button"
  - else
    %td= button_to_function "unlock", User.unlock_user(user.id), :class => "unlock_button"*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a model method directly from a view.

You need to create an action on your controller, and call the model method there.

The basic workflow is:

```
Link in View -> Url -> Controller.Action -> Model ->Method.
```